How should I stop a thread from the outside in Rust?
I have a thread that receives messages and does something with them in a loop.
I want to stop that thread from the outside. The thread should stop as soon as possible and discard the remaining messages. What is the best way to do that?
I didn't find anything to interrupt the thread from the outside. So my idea was to use a shared AtomicBool that could be set from the outside and would be checked inside the thread. But the thread can not check the AtomicBool while it is waiting for a message, so I'm also sending an empty message after setting the AtomicBool.
Here is code to illustrate
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        mpsc::{Receiver, Sender},
        Arc,
    },
    thread::{self, JoinHandle},
};

type Message = Option<u32>;

pub struct MessageHandler {
    cancel_token: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    pub sender: Sender<Message>,
    join_handle: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl MessageHandler {
    pub fn new() -> MessageHandler {
        let cancel_token = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

        let join_handle = {
            let cancel_token = cancel_token.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                MessageHandler::handle_messages(receiver, cancel_token);
            })
        };

        MessageHandler {
            cancel_token,
            sender,
            join_handle: Some(join_handle),
        }
    }

    pub fn send_message(&self, number: u32) {
        self.sender.send(Some(number)).unwrap();
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.cancel_token.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.sender.send(None).unwrap();
        self.join_handle.take().unwrap().join();
    }

    fn handle_messages(receiver: Receiver<Message>, cancel_token: Arc<AtomicBool>) {
        for message in receiver {
            if cancel_token.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                return;
            }

            if let Some(_) = message {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm not really happy with that. It probably would work almost always. But can I really be sure that from the perspective of the thread the AtomicBool is set before the message is received? For all I know I can't (What does the Ordering in the AtomicBool operations do?). Of course I could just end the thread when None is received, then it wouldn't matter if the AtomicBool is set to late.
Is there a better solution for the problem?

Your cancel_token approach will work. You can trust any memory ordering (including Relaxed) to load the AtomicBool since the channel does sufficient internal atomic operations such as the Sender calling Thread::unpark to wake up the Receiver, which is guaranteed to synchronize the store before the load. If you're still curious, you can read about memory orderings in the documentation of std::sync::atomic::Ordering and the linked C++ memory orders on which Rust is based.
Rust doesn't support preemptively terminating threads. In this case, your thread must block on receiving a message from a channel. Rather than sending an empty message, you can exploit the fact that a Receiver::recv with an empty buffer will wake up and return Err (as opposed to Ok) when the corresponding Sender is dropped:
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        mpsc::{Receiver, Sender},
        Arc,
    },
    thread::{self, JoinHandle},
};

type Message = u32;

pub struct MessageHandler {
    sender: Option<Sender<Message>>,
    join_handle: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    cancel_token: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl MessageHandler {
    pub fn new() -> MessageHandler {
        let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

        let cancel_token = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let join_handle = {
            let cancel_token = Arc::clone(&cancel_token);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                MessageHandler::handle_messages(receiver, cancel_token);
            })
        };

        MessageHandler {
            cancel_token,
            sender: Some(sender),
            join_handle: Some(join_handle),
        }
    }

    pub fn send_message(&self, number: u32) {
        if let Some(sender) = self.sender.as_ref() {
            sender.send(number).unwrap();
        } else {
            panic!("send after stopped");
        }
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.cancel_token.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
        drop(std::mem::take(&mut self.sender));
        self.join_handle.take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
    }

    fn handle_messages(receiver: Receiver<Message>, cancel_token: Arc<AtomicBool>) {
        while let Ok(_message) = receiver.recv() {
            if cancel_token.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                break;
            }
            // do something
        }
    }
}


To be clear, the for message in receiver { ... } syntax you were using would also terminate the loop when the Sender is dropped. I just thought while let Ok(message) = receiver.recv() would make this answer more clear.
Alternatively, if your timing requirement was less strict, you could use Receiver::recv_timeout to periodically check for cancellation:
    fn handle_messages(receiver: Receiver<Message>, cancel_token: Arc<AtomicBool>) {
        loop {
            let result = receiver.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1));
            if cancel_token.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                break;
            }
            match result {
                Ok(_message) => {
                    // do something
                }
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Timeout) => {}
                Err(RecvTimeoutError::Disconnected) => {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


As far as I know, Receiver::recv will only return Err if every Sender is dropped and the queue is empty. There could still be messages in the queue and clones of the sender when I call stop. The thread should stop as soon as possible and discard the remaining messages.

@Hirnlos ah yes, good catch! I added back the cancel_token. You mention clones of the sender. Currently that's impossible as MessageHander::stop takes a mutable reference to MessageHandler which contains the only Sender. If you wanted to make it possible to Clone::clone the MessageHandler, you could use Arc<RwLock<Option<Sender<Messsage>>>> instead of Option<Sender<Message>>. Sending would lock the sender for reading. Stopping would lock the sender for writing and then drop it. However, once you reach that level of complexity, your original approach might be preferable.

I just added a second approach, using recv_timeout, which would seamlessly support the case of multiple Sender's.

@user4815162342 By your logic, Mutex<AtomicUsize>.lock().unwrap().atomic_op(..., Ordering::Relaxed) wouldn't work, but it does work. Run with Miri to simulate maximum synchronization chaos, and the the non-Mutex one usually comes up short.

*to be clear, I'm not saying that working in Miri guarantees validity. My larger point is that Mutex wouldn't work at all if what you said was true. Normal Mutex critical sections do non-atomic operations which have even fewer constraints than Relaxed-atomic. Do you have a source for your blanket statement "Relaxed can be arbitrarily reordered in terms of other memory operations, including atomic ones (on other atomics)"?
